# Custom delimited text file from dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark 1.6 and trying to create a delimited file from the dataframe.

The field delimiter is '|^', so I'm concatenating the columns from the dataframe while selecting from the temp table

Now the below code fails everytime with this error

```
ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 172 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
19/03/01 09:10:15 ERROR datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 172 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 172.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 1397, tplhc01d104.iuser.iroot.adidom.com, executor 7): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:272
```

The Code I'm using is this..

```
tempDF.registerTempTable("BNUC_TEMP")

context.sql("select concat('VALID','|^', RECORD_ID,'|^', DATA_COL1,'|^', DATA_COL2,'|^','P','|^', DATA_COL4,'|^', DATA_COL5,'|^', DATA_COL6,'GBP','|^',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( ACTION_DATE)),'|^',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( UPDATED_DATE))) from BNUC_TEMP")
.write.mode("overwrite")
.text("/user/USERNAME/landing/staging/BNU/temp/")
```

Comment: Could you describe a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to test against and better help you and future readers of this question?

Comment: Hello @Dixon could you post some sample data?